# Error's when adding code to c++ winAPI script

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, file-upload, visual-studio-2013

I have a code base that checks for a button press, and I want to connect to a server whenever I click on the button, but when I add the following code -

includes

```
#include <atlstr.h>
#include <stdafx.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "P2GoVideoUploader2.0.h"
#include "libobs/obs.h"
#include "libobs/obs-module.h"

#include <WinInet.h>
```

defines

```
#define uploadName "Upload Window"
#define uploadWNDWidth 500
#define uploadWNDHeight 500
#define IDC_SELECT_VIDEO (100)
#define IDC_UPLOAD_VIDEO (99)

HWND  hBtnParent = HWND("UploadVideo");
HWND SelectVideoBTN, UploadBTN, hWnd, hBtn;

WPARAM wmId, wmEvent;

HINSTANCE hUpload;

WNDCLASSEX wcexUpload;

int nCmdShowUpload = 1;

using namespace std;
```

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

```
    HINTERNET hTest;
    HINTERNET hFTP;
    hTest = InternetOpen(NULL, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);
```

to -

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_COMMAND:
        if (wParam == IDC_SELECT_VIDEO) {
            //code goes here
            }

        else if (wParam == IDC_UPLOAD_VIDEO){
            MessageBox(hWnd, L"something", L"else", 0);
        }
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return wParam;
}
```

I these errors -

```
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__InternetOpenW@20 referenced in function "long __stdcall WindowProcedure(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned int,long)" (?WindowProcedure@@YGJPAUHWND__@@IIJ@Z)
Error   6   error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

The first error happens in -`projfile.obj` and the second error happens in `projfile.dll`

I've found the code on - http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/29994-c-ftp-upload-help/ & i've tried multiple other upload examples, but they all result in similiar errors, why am I getting these error's?

My project is a `Win32 Project`, I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Don't include windows if it is already included and make sure you aren't using variables and declarations in the global namespace as well.

Comment: I'm only including windows once

Comment: MFC apps tend to include windows already or you can make an include file that uses #pragma once to ensure it is only called once.  Although looking at the error you probably don't want to include it.  You may need to choose a different project type

Comment: You are mixing ATL/MFC and plain Windows API includes. When using ATL/MFC you should not include *Windows.h* yourself, but rather include *afx.h* instead (it will include *Windows.h* at the right time). Also, those IntelliSense errors can be ignored. They are not compiler/linker errors (or warnings). Unrelated, but `HWND("UploadVideo")` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm now getting errors that it doesn't know hInternet or FTP_TRANSFER_TYPE_BINARY even though I include WinInet.h and winhttp.h

Comment: & I've removed the windows.h and I've added afx.h, but it's still giving the intellisense error, I guess that I'll ignore that, and focus on the 'actual' errors

Comment: Your includes are a big mess. They are not in the [original code](http://www.rohitab.com/discuss/topic/29994-c-ftp-upload-help/) that you link, which presumably works just fine on its own. Do yourself a favor and blow away the whole lot. Your code file should include only your precompiled header, `"stdafx.h"`. That precompiled header would include `<afx.h>` and any *specific* Windows and C lib headers that you require. As already mentioned, if you're using ATL/MFC, you should include *those* headers, *not* the generic Win32 SDK headers. A blank, empty Win32 project from VS will get you going.

Comment: I've cleaned up my includes, to the basic libs that I needed & removed the somewhat useless IntelliSense errors, because they can be ignored

Comment: You have to link to wininet.lib library. See MSDN documentation for InternetOpen

Comment: @BarmakShemirani that fixed it, if you could please answer my question so that I can accept it

Comment: Your error was originally something else, and the topic doesn't match unresolved link. You can add the answer yourself. I don't think you are using precompiled headers, so don't included `"stdafx.h"`. If you are using precompiled headers, then `"stdafx.h"` should be on line 1, included before everything else. Otherwise you only need `"windows.h"` and `"wininet.h"` for this code. Also remove `HWND("UploadVideo")`

Comment: winInet.h and winhttp were colliding, if I included both they gave me an error, that was the first issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to link to wininet.lib library, in VS2013 do -

Project -> Project Properties -> Linker -> input -> add to additional dependencies

& since someone mentioned the first error, that it was something different, WinInet.h and winhttp.h were colliding, if I included both it wouldn't compile, so I removed winhttp.h